# How to check for empty collection or its property in jpql

Tags: hibernate, jpql

I have a tables named visit and providers.

Visit can have multiple providers or no providers.

One visit can have many providers.

I want a jpql query which should list all the visits for a provider.

To list a visit either the provider Id should match or the visit should not had any providers assigned.

I tried like this

```
From visit v join
v.providers p
where( p.provider.id =:providerId 
or p is empty)
```

But this is not listing visits without the provider.

Please helpe on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the order of the conditions in your `WHERE` clause and maybe add a `NULL` check as well:

```
From visit v join
v.providers p
where(p IS NULL OR p IS EMPTY OR p.provider.id = :providerId)
```